# Non-systematic (7, 4) Hamming code encoder

Tags: encoder

I have to do the scheme of the non-systematic Hamming code encoder (not cyclic but classic). But I have not found any source where it would be written how to build a generating matrix and create a system of linear equations for finding symbols of code combinations. How is this done?

Once again, I consider the non-systematic classical (n, k) Hamming code. For example, (7, 4) Hamming code.

Thank you in advance for your detailed answers.

Comment: (7,4) Hamming is really easy to understand. I'm not sure how it could be a struggle. But are you asking for something far more general?

Comment: He's looking for the XOR parity codecs

Comment: Just to get the link into here: [Hamming](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/378915/hamming-code-circuit/378990#378990).

Comment: @jonk Systematic Hamming code is really easy to understand. But the unsystematic is not clear. For example, there is a matrix G of an unsystematic (7, 4) Hamming code. How to create a system of linear equations for finding symbols of code combinations? $$G = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS I recall from the '70's it uses XOR gates but now in a small CPLD.
    P1=d0 ⊕ d2 ⊕ d4 ⊕ d6
    P2=d1 ⊕ d2 ⊕ d4 ⊕ d6
    P3=d3 ⊕ d4 ⊕ d5⊕ d6

**b3, b2, b1, P3, b0, P2, P1**  7 bit string =  3 parity bits +  4 data bits  = Hamming 7,4
sent as   **d6 d5 d4 d3 d2 d1 d0**    repeat for both 4b nibble to get 14 bit string.

Dave? @Jonk correct me if I missed something.

Comment: You are right, but you described a systematic (7, 4)-code. Non-systematic should work differently, because the test matrix is chaotic.

Comment: Not so chaotic, just funky:  swap 2 columns, then XOR 2 or 3 rows and replace any  row with result.  But repeat same for G matrix decoder.

Comment: As I understand it, is not necessary to rearrange only 2 columns (can be any number). For example, $$G = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: But then it turns out that the test matrix will look like this: $$H = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & * & * & * \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & * & * & * \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & * & * & *\end{pmatrix}$$ How do I determine the remaining " * * *"columns?

Comment: Looks that way! As long as identical sequential operations are done, 1⊕1=0

Comment: \begin{matrix} {H= \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\ 0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\ 1&0&1&0&1&0&1 \end{bmatrix}} \\ {C_{7} \leftrightarrow C_{1}}\\ {H_{1}= \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&1&1&1&0\\ 1&1&1&0&0&1&0\\ 1&0&1&0&1&0&1 \end{bmatrix}}\\ {C_{2} \leftrightarrow C_{6}}\\ {H_{2}= \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0&1&1&0&0\\ 1&1&1&0&0&1&0\\ 1&0&1&0&1&0&1 \end{bmatrix}}\\ {C_{4} \leftrightarrow C_{5}}\\ {H_{3}= \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0&1&1&0&0\\ 1&1&1&0&0&1&0\\ 1&0&1&1&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}}\\ \end{matrix}

Comment: \begin{matrix} {H_{4}=\left[ \begin{array}{cccccc|c} 1&1&0&1&1&0&0\\ 1&1&1&0&0&1&0\\ 1&0&1&1&0&0&1\end{array} \right]}\\ {\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;A\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;I_{3}} \end{matrix}

Comment: $$GH^{T}=0$$  Now if you understand this write your own answer

Comment: \begin{matrix} {G_{3}=\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|ccc} 1&0&0&0&1&1&1\\ 0&1&0&0&1&1&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0&1&1\\ 0&0&0&1&1&0&1\end{array} \right]}\\ {\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;I_{4}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; A^{T}} \end{matrix}

Comment: \begin{matrix} {C_{4} \leftrightarrow C_{5}}\\ {G_{2}=\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|ccc} 1&0&0&1&0&1&1\\ 0&1&0&1&0&1&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0&1&1\\ 0&0&0&1&1&0&1\end{array} \right]}\\ {C_{2} \leftrightarrow C_{6}}\\ {G_{1}=\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|ccc} 1&1&0&1&0&0&1\\ 0&1&0&1&0&1&0\\ 0&1&1&0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&1&1&0&1\end{array} \right]}\\ {C_{7} \leftrightarrow C_{1}}\\ {G=\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|ccc} 1&1&0&1&0&0&1\\ 0&1&0&1&0&1&0\\ 1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\ 1&0&0&1&1&0&0\end{array} \right]}\end{matrix}

Comment: G times  H transposed  \$GH^T=0\$

Comment: $$GH^T=0$$ Thus, if $$G = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ that $$H = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Can U paste into Answer

Comment: And this test matrix H can be considered as non-systematic? Since it is obtained from the non-systematic matrix G.

Comment: Yes That’s what it seems, since you create your own sequence and reverse it like CRC